# Question about descent directions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $D_f (x)$ be the set of descent directions of $f$ at $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

Prove that
$$
d \in D_f (x) \Rightarrow \langle \nabla f(x), d\rangle 
$$
and

if $\langle \nabla f(x), d\rangle < 0$  then $d \in D_f (x)$

I have an idea of proving this with a linear Taylor approximation, but it doesn't seem to formal.

Comment: include your current working and also your statement seems not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ is a descent direction then for $\varepsilon$ small enough,
$$\frac{f(x+\varepsilon d) - f(x)}{\varepsilon} \leq 0.$$
This implies by taking the limit $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ that
$$\langle \nabla f(x) ,d \rangle \leq 0.$$

Alternatively, if $\langle \nabla f(x) ,d \rangle < 0$ then for some $\varepsilon > 0$, by continuity/definition of the limit, we must also have
$$\frac{f(x+\varepsilon d) - f(x)}{\varepsilon} \leq 0.$$
This is no longer necessarily true if we only have $\langle \nabla f(x) ,d \rangle \leq 0$.